# importError: No module named django.core.wsgi while using openstack dashboard

Tags: django, openstack, openstack-horizon, horizon

I am using Openstack Liberty and Ubuntu 14.04. 
After installing openstack dashboard , things were working pretty fine and then I decided to uninstall and reinstall the openstack dashboard package due to a colleague configuring SSL wrongly and changing the dashboard theme to customize it. Now,  I get the following error .

```
mod_wsgi (pid=30567, process='horizon', application='cpph-ch01-blade02|/horizon'): Loading WSGI script '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi'.
sys.path is: ['/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Target WSGI script '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi'.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
[:error] [pid 30567:tid 140400988059392]  File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
[:error] [pid 30567:tid 140400988059392]  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[:error] [pid 30567:tid 140400988059392]  ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

In the target script shown below, I print the syspath . Not sure if this matters but I have the target wsgi script at 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py

```
 1 import logging
 2 import os
 3 import sys
 4 # print
 5 print >>sys.stderr, "sys.path is: " + str(sys.path)
 6 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 7 from django.conf import settings
 8 # Add this file path to sys.path in order to import settings
 9 sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../..'))
 10 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'openstack_dashboard.settings'
 11 sys.stdout = sys.stderr
 12 sys.path.append("/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/")
 13 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have tried reinstalling it multiple times to no avail and I cant reinstall python as this is a production environment.  Presently, I have installed the dashboard on a different host and connected it to my production server as a work around.

I am not a python developer and have not used virtual environement or anything related to development for this, it was a simple apt-get installation.

Comment: Are you sure the application is loading your target script at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py`? The traceback seems to indicate that it is trying to load `/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi` and it is that script that cannot load `django.core.wsgi`

Comment: True. I just printed it out thinking it could be of some relevance since I am not a python or django developer. The script was part of the openstack dashboard. I have never edited it before to get the dashboard working. Could you suggest some means of troubleshooting this?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the Horizon dashboard, but it may be worth looking at the mod_wsgi configuration to see whether it is correctly referencing your target script. It looks as though Horizon offers a Django management command to help you with the setup (although I guess you may already have done this): https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/install/from-source.html#deployment

Comment: Thank you.  I used a much direct method apt-get install openstack-dashboard as per the documentation. I am considering giving this a try.